# Error: dot support for x of rank 4 is not yet implemented

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am using Tensorflow.js to predict on a model I trained in Keras. However, when I feed in my 4-dimensional tensor I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: dot support for x of rank 4 is not yet implemented: x shape = 32,1,1,100
```

I can't find anything on the web about this error- I suspect it has something to do with Tensorflow.js not having this capability yet but I'm not sure. Any idea where I can get more information?

### Edit 1

Here is my code, the line throwing the error is `model.predict(noise_tensor)`. Most of the code proceeding it is irrelevant:

```
  noise_tensor.print(true)

  generated_images = model.predict(noise_tensor) //error occours here
```

Here is the print output of my 4d tensor:

```
Tensor
  dtype: float32
  rank: 4
  shape: [64,1,1,100]
  values:
    [ [ [[0.3799773 , -0.0252707, 0.0118336 , ..., 0.1703698 , -0.0649208, 0.2152225 ],]],


      [ [[0.219656  , 0.2850143 , -0.1078744, ..., 0.1627689 , -0.0838831, -0.1112608],]],


      [ [[-0.1295149, -0.08308  , 0.1872116 , ..., -0.2033772, -0.4184959, -0.3357461],]],


     ...
      [ [[0.0029674 , 0.0422036 , 0.067896  , ..., 0.1368463 , 0.1122015 , -0.0395375],]],


      [ [[0.043546  , -0.0281712, 0.0898769 , ..., 0.205565  , 0.1444133 , 0.0067788 ],]],


      [ [[-0.1089588, -0.0161969, -0.0724337, ..., 0.1427118 , -0.2577117, 0.0013836 ],]]]
```

Here is the summary of the Keras model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1, 1, 32768)       3309568
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 16, 16, 256)       3277056
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 128)       819328
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 64, 64)        204864
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 64, 64, 64)        256
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 128, 1)       1601
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 128, 128, 1)       0
=================================================================
Total params: 7,616,257
Trainable params: 7,614,337
Non-trainable params: 1,920
_________________________________________________________________
```

and the corresponding code in Python:

```
def construct_generator():

    generator = Sequential()

    generator.add(Dense(units=8 * 8 * 512,
                        kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                        input_shape=(1, 1, 100)))
    generator.add(Reshape(target_shape=(8, 8, 512)))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.5))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                  strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.5))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                  strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.5))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                  strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.5))
    generator.add(Activation('relu'))

    generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                  strides=(2, 2), padding='same',
                                  data_format='channels_last',
                                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))
    generator.add(Activation('tanh'))

    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.00015, beta_1=0.5)
    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=optimizer,
                      metrics=None)

    print('generator')
    generator.summary()

    return generator
```

### Edit 2

This is a bug in tensorflow.js. For future visitors, please take a look a the GitHub thread [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/632).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the inputs should be of rank 1 or 2 for `tf.dot` to work

Comment: Forgive me for my naivety, but I'm not calling `tf.dot` directly, I'm only calling `tf.model.predict`. Is there a way I can circumvent the subsequent call to `tf.dot` by modifying my model ? I will attach my code to the main post

Comment: Could you please put the code and tell the line throwing the error ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I attached all my code which I think could be relevant above in the main post. I think some of it is redundant, but for reference I posted it anyway. Let me know if I can supply/ clarify anything. Thanks again

Comment: what is your model like ?

Comment: Ah sorry. I added it and removed it again because I thought the block of code was scaring people away from the question. I added the code for the model again

Comment: Though I cannot say if for sure, it seems that one of the transformation functions uses `tf.dot` internally. You can consider filling an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues)

Comment: Thank you, I'll do so. I'm not going to accept your answer yet, just so that hopefully this question will attract others who may have some insight. If nobody else responds I'll come back and accept your answer in a day or so. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It turns out it's a bug in tensorflow.js. For future visitors to this post, please take a look at the thread on github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/632)